How to Configure GitHub Actions for Laravel Project to Build and Push Docker Image to Docker Hub?
'm working on a project built with:

Laravel 10

Tailwind

MySQL


I want to automate the process where every time I push to GitHub, GitHub Actions will run tests, build the project, and push the Docker image to Docker Hub. I can then pull it from Docker Hub and run the project. However, I am having trouble setting up the .yml file and Dockerfile properly.
Here is my GitHub Actions configuration (laravel.yml):
name: Laravel CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
        env:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.1'
          extensions: mbstring, pdo_mysql, bcmath
          ini-values: post_max_size=256M, max_execution_time=300

      - name: Cache Composer dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor
          key: composer-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
          restore-keys: composer-

      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest

      - name: Setup .env file
        run: |
          cp .env.example .env
          php artisan key:generate

      - name: Run database migrations
        run: php artisan migrate --force

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: mydockerhubusername/myproject:latest

Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

COPY --from=composer:2.6 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts --prefer-dist

COPY . .

RUN mkdir -p storage bootstrap/cache

RUN chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

RUN npm install && npm run build

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]

Problem:

Sometimes the build works but the Laravel app shows a blank white page after deployment.

Other times, I get connection reset errors.

I am unsure if my Dockerfile or .yml is correctly configured for pushing and pulling from Docker Hub.


Could you help me identify any issues with my setup? What am I missing or doing wrong to achieve the desired outcome?

what does curl -I YOURIP shows?

I think your problem will be solved by clearing the cache. Take a look at this file. https://github.com/pinkary-project/pinkary.com/blob/main/forge-deployment.sh
